# Integration test with authorization and authentication in asp.net core mvc .net 8

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, integration-testing

I am using external service for authentication purposes in my MVC app. I have a callback that gives me a JWT token. I am validating JWT token and if it is valid, I am creating a cookie like this:

```
public class AuthorizationController(IConfiguration configuration) : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> CallBack(string atoken)
    {
        var key = configuration["JWT:Secret"];
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var res = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(atoken, new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey =
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        }, out _);
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(res.Claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.MaxValue,
                AllowRefresh = true
            });
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "PagesView");
    }
}
```

and I put Authorization attribute to my other controllers. And here is authorization config:

```
   services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Authorization/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    });
```

Now, I want to create an integration test for my app:

```
[Test]
public async Task PostNewPage_Test()
{
    await AddRoleAuthorization(ApplicationClaimValues.SuperAdministrator);
    var command = new CreateContentCommand
    {
        PageName = _page.Name,
        Title = "title",
        Lang = "ru",
        HtmlContent = "fasdfasdf"
    };
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsFormAsync(CreateContentUrl, command);
    Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
}
```

And there is my AddRoleAuthorization method:

```
protected async Task AddRoleAuthorization(string role)
{
    using var scope = _factory.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>()!.CreateScope();
    var token = _tokenService.CreateTokenByClaims(_jwtSecret,
    [
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role),
    ]);
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"/Authorization/callback?token={token}");
    foreach (var item in response.Headers)
    {
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

The problem is it has a cookie value on headers before sending post request, but it is giving me redirect status code to my AuthorizationController which means client is not authorized. So, how to setup up my httpclient properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codes looks correct but make sure you have set the `HttpClientHandler` with `UseCookies` to true which can help yu save and share the cookie between the request and because of that your request wont be unauthorized and will not get redirect to the AuthorizationController.

You could try below updated code to resolve your issue:

Set up the `HttpClientHandler` with a `CookieContainer`

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
   {
       UseCookies = true,
       CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
       AllowAutoRedirect = false 
   };

   _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

AddRoleAuthorization:

```
protected async Task AddRoleAuthorization(string role)
   {
       var token = _tokenService.CreateTokenByClaims(_jwtSecret, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
       var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"/Authorization/callback?token={token}");

       if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
       {
           var redirectUri = response.Headers.Location;
           response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(redirectUri);
       }
   }
```